# Length size in etext format(BI reporting)

Tags: sql, bi-publisher

I have a requirement to have length of only 32 size.
I used RPAD in my sql query to handle it.

Now, In my report, it's allocating 32 bits space. I want the field content to auto fit in the report.
How to do that in Rtf template?

Comment: The second column in your etext template should be for column. You can specify the length there and anything more than that will be trimmed.

Comment: Please provide some more details. For example, are you doing fixed width, or delimited? What does the line you are looking to fix look like in the eText template? What does the XML data look like? What is the current output? What is the output you are expecting?